# Scrolling blocks of variable width images in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**TASK DETAILS:**

1. There is gallery on page, all images previews are loaded on page.
2. Images are shown by BLOCK OF IMAGES (1 block on page, fixed block
   width & height).
3. All images are variable width, but same height (so can be
   different number of images in block).

**PROBLEM:**

Make scrolling by blocks when pressing on navigation buttons on page

```
    =======================
<-  =  xx  sss  dd  qqqq  =  ->
    =======================
```

`xx`  and so on - different images in gallery

`===` border of images block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting width of images in block and forming arrays of images for each block, what was my first idea, suddenly I found much more simple and nice solution for such task:

### GENERAL IDEA DESCRIPTION WITH SCHEMA:

All images page schema:

```
    -----------------------
    -  ff  ll  mmmm  aa   -
    -=====================-
<-  -  eeee  bbb  dd  ppp -  ->
    -=====================-        
    -  xx  sss  kk  qqqq  -
    -----------------------
```

`ff`  and so on - different images in gallery (`float: left`; for each img)

`---` marked block of ***#all_images*** (`overflow: hidden; possition: absolute; top: ***`)

`===` marked block of ***#visible_frame*** (`position: absolute;`)

When navigation buttons on page are pressed, we make +/- to `top` value of ***#all_images*** and as result in **#visible_frame** will show different set of images.