# Scrolling gallery block of images to the place of current image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have found interesting solution for scrolling blocks of images in gallery, which I described here in details here: [Scrolling blocks of variable width images in gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497383/scrolling-blocks-of-variable-width-images-in-gallery/11497384#11497384)

### But I met one problem:

**For example I am on full page of img 'sss', how can I link from this page to all imgs page so, that propper block will be showed (scrolled to the block possition), if I know only name\href of current image, but don't know number of block (and don't want to implement code for counting blocks from width of images)?**

### Logic of scrolling working in my gallery:

```
    -----------------------
    -  ff  ll  mmmm  aa   -
    =======================
<-  =  eee  bbb  dd  ppp  =  ->
    =======================        
    -  xx  sss  dd  qqqq  -
    -----------------------
```

`ff`  and so on - different images in gallery (`float: left`; for each img)

`---` marked block of ***#all_images*** (`overflow: hidden; possition: absolute; top: ***`)

`===` marked block of ***#visible_frame*** (`possition: absolute;`)

So when navigation pressed, I'll make +/- to `top` value of ***#all_images*** and as result in ***#visible_frame*** will be different set of images

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the image, you should have no problem finding which row/block it's in and finding its offset x/y position and adjusting your gallery accordingly.

You'll have to loop through all the images on the page and find the matching source.

Also, I've used [this jquery plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) in the past for scrolling to positions on the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the plugin - I'll try it soon. But how can it be done in clear JavaScript/JQuery - can you give some ideas?